# Charging customer with saved card in main account with connected account in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I know I can save a card with a customer in Stripe and use it for later.  My question is can I save the customer with the card on the main Stripe onboarding account and use that customer for all sub accounts (connected accounts). Or does the customer have to be created and saved on each connected account to work.

[Stripe Payment: Save token and customer and make payment later from token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374282/stripe-payment-save-token-and-customer-and-make-payment-later-from-token)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe connected accounts would need to have copies of those customers and cards associated with their accounts to be able to process charges for those cards/customers.

There are ways to copy payment methods from the Platform to the Connected account that are detailed [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#cloning-payment-methods) which you might find useful.

Comment: That is it, and what Stripe chat support told me